# Repeatonnewpage tablix property already set to true but tables is still cut

Tags: vb.net

here's my output[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gcn7F.png) and here's my report design[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzF1M.png)
Im working with reportviewer for my reports.i have a report that is consist of a table, my problem is I have 2 rows that is static in that table and I also have to set the minimum number of rows for that table  since the minimum number of rows I have to set for the table exceeds the page I need to repeat the 2 static rows for the next page I already set its set its Repeatonnewpage =true and keep with group = after but my table is still cut.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Probably you changed this options in the Tablix Properties. Try this:

Click in "Advanced Options"

[Advanced Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRAIm.png)

Change the Static label properties of your Header Repeatonnewpage = true

[Propeties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlnkO.png)

Comment: I already edited my post sir, please check the pictures above

Comment: Seams to be all configured right. Check if all possible labels in the header are with Repeatonnewpage = true. When you added this extra line in header did you Inserted row inside or outside group ? Is important to be outside group.

Comment: It's inside the group except for those rows between the total and the obrdate row.

Comment: Try to delete one row where is write "reference" and let de header with just one row. If works, try add the row again but select option "insert row outside group". If don't work try stay with just one row in  the header.